# After flashing ROM in Odin, reboot with animation, message pop ups - processes stop

Tags: rom, odin

I flash  NEW ROM and after reboot, the samsung animation came up.

But there as it load there are messages saying the process stop, I press Ok and next message is another process stop - such as a.core.process, gmap amanger, etc.

Pls help

Comment: It may help if you post the exact (error) messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the data (performing a factory reset) from your recovery.  Some custom ROMs need this, for whatever reason.